# How can fetch a variable in sql to php according to post id?

Tags: php, sql, fetch

I want to calculate the sum of the rank of a post and publish(echo) it according to the post id on my page. but fetch_assoc gives this error:
Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to undefined function fetch_assoc() in C:\xampp\htdocs...

my code:

```
$sql_rank="SELECT SUM(rank_n) FROM ranking WHERE post_id = ? ";
$stmt7 = $con -> prepare($sql_rank);
$stmt7 -> bind_param('i', $_post['post_id']);
$stmt7 -> execute();
$stmt7 -> bind_result($rank_n);
while($row = fetch_assoc()){
    echo $row["SUM(rank_n)"]; 
}
```

I fixed this error and it properly works! look at the edited code below:

```
<?php 
$sql_rank="SELECT SUM(rank_n) AS rank_total FROM ranking WHERE post_id = ? ";
$result = $con -> prepare($sql_rank);
$result -> bind_param('i', $_GET['id']);
$result -> execute();
$result -> bind_result($rank_total);
$result -> fetch();
echo $rank_total;
?>
```

Comment: `fetch_assoc()` needs to be called on a mysqli_result object.

Comment: $stmt7->fetch_assoc()